# Boost serialization/deserialization archive "stream error" exception

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, stream

I've the following problem..

I have a file called A.h and a file B.h. each  contains some struct like this: (the structs inside the two classes are different)

```
struct Base
{
    friend class access;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar,const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & fieldLength;
        ar & fieldMD;
        ar & fieldTime_Stamp;
    }   
   public:
        unsigned int fieldLength;
        unsigned int fieldMD;
        unsigned int fieldTime_Stamp;

       virtual void f(){} //to be polymorphic the struct
};

struct Derived:public Base
{
    ...
}
```

So i serialize the struct in the classic manner:

```
....

std::ostringstream archive_stream;

boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);

archive.register_type(static_cast<Derived*>(NULL))

archive <<p;   // where p is a pointer to Base
```

NOW THE PROBLEM...
on the deserialization side, I follow the same (inverse) procedure...if I deserialize singularly the structs in A.h (without include in the project B.h) and the structs in B.h (without include in the project A.h) all works....but If I include in the project both the classes, the deserialization  works for one class, but  throws the "Stream error exception" in the  instruction   " archive >> m;" for the other...it seems a conflict in the registration class or something like this...
Any ideas?thanks...

Comment: Show your actual deserialization code.

Comment: std::istringstream archive_stream(mex); //mex is the serialized    data       received form the socket
 
      boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);

      archive.register_type(static_cast<Derived*>(NULL));
      ...
 
                                                         Base* m;

      archive >> m;

Comment: I've observed that I have a conflict on registration of the class through the archive.register_type(), despite I create two (local)text_iarchive in  separate processes(I use the fork call)...in fact, if I comment the registration code of the second process, all works...how is it possible?

Comment: If you use fork, you have to do the registration either before the fork (once) or after the fork (twice, one in each process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you serialised the base data in the derived class serialize function?

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp( "base", boost::serialization::base_object< Base >( *this ) );
```

And I dont know if this would help, but I use

```
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(x, boost::serialization::object_serializable);
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(x, boost::serialization::track_never)
```

to register the classes as serialiseable. Hope that helps :3